# Add class name of content, Hypernate doesn't work to IE and Chrome

Tags: posts

I am using the `hyphenator.js` to custom page template and works for paragraph, but I can not apply it to Post. How can do that?

`header.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/bramstein/hypher/master/dist/jquery.hypher.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)
    {
     $(function() {
     $('p').hyphenate('en');
      });
    });
    </script>
```

`style.css`

```
post-single {text-align:justify; font-size:1em;}
```

`single-news.php`

```
<div class="post-single" id="post-<?php the_ID();?>">
<div class="title-single"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3> </div>
<div class="posted">
<em>Posted <?php the_time('l, j F Y') ?>.</em></div>

        <?php the_content (); ?>

</div>
```

The problem with the class resolved, but the `hypernate .js` doesn't work to IE. How can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

While inserting js directly in `header.php`can work it's not recommanded to do that. You'd better add your scripts to the WordPress queue:

```
function wpse_109879_insert_hyphenator() {
 wp_register_script('hyphenator', 'https://raw.github.com/bramstein/hypher/master/dist/jquery.hypher.js', array('jquery'), null , false);
 wp_enqueue_script('hyphenator');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','wpse_109879_insert_hyphenator');
```

Regarding CSS you probably use the wrong class, you can try `.single-post` or `.single`

**EDIT:** I see you use raw script. Maybe you'd better copy paste code from github into another js file you can call directly from your theme. This would allow to insert code you use to initialize hyphenator so you have only one file to manage hyphenator.

Comment: i add more information about 'single-news.php'. If i add his script to WP queue, the `hyphenator` don't work for custom page template.

Comment: After many times of efforts. Ι "reload" the js of language and the script load for paragraphs of post. I think that the problem, that the problem resolved but I say that with caution.

Comment: But the text-justify and `hyphenator.js` doesn't work for other browsers like Chrome and IE. How can fix that?